# python extract values from complex nested dictionary and list

Tags: python, python-2.7

Although, I came across many examples for nested dictionary but I'm unable to crack this one! Following is input in json format and my desired output as below. 
The input dictionary is with more than 100 entries and I would like to extract values for only few selected variables (Like IP address, Med , Active).

For some entries 'med' is nested inside list of [0,1,2 etc]

> med = bgp['10.0.0.0/16']['bgpRoutePaths'][0].get('med')
>   med = bgp['10.0.0.0/16']['bgpRoutePaths'][1].get('med')

```
Input:

    {u'10.0.0.0/16': {u'address': u'10.0.0.0',
                          u'bgpAdvertisedPeerGroups': {},
                          u'bgpRoutePaths': [{u'asPathEntry': {u'asPath': u'65404,65315 i',              
                                                               u'asPathType': None},
                                              u'localPreference': 100,
                                              u'med': 0,
                                              u'nextHop': u'172.1.1.169',
                                              u'routeType': {u'active': True,
                                                             u'atomicAggregator': False,
                                                             u'backup': False,
                                                             u'ecmp': False,
                                                             u'ecmpContributor': False,
                                                             u'ecmpHead': False,
                                                             u'queued': False,
                                                             u'stale': False,
                                                             u'suppressed': False,
                                                             u'ucmp': False,
                                                             u'valid': True},
                                              u'weight': 0},
                                             {u'asPathEntry': {u'asPath': u'65407  65315 65317 65000 i',
                                                               u'asPathType': None},
                                              u'localPreference': 100,
                                              u'med': 0,
                                              u'nextHop': u'172.16.1.94',
                                              u'routeType': {u'active': False,
                                                             u'atomicAggregator': False,
                                                             u'backup': False,
                                                             u'ecmp': False,
                                                             u'ecmpContributor': False,
                                                             u'ecmpHead': False,
                                                             u'queued': False,
                                                             u'stale': False,
                                                             u'suppressed': False,
                                                             u'ucmp': False,
                                                             u'valid': True},
                                              u'weight': 0}],
                          u'maskLength': 16},
}
```

Output:

```
IPaddr         asPath                               med  active
10.0.0.0/16    (65404 65315 i)                       0    True
10.0.0.0/16    (65407 65315 65317 65000 i)           0    False
```

Comment: What's your actual problem?

Answer (score 0):

Consider your dictionary as variable 'a' then you can access the data by

```
print a.keys()[0]
print a['10.0.0.0/16']['bgpRoutePaths'][0]['asPathEntry']['asPath'], ' ', a['10.0.0.0/16']['bgpRoutePaths'][0]['med'], ' ', a['10.0.0.0/16']['bgpRoutePaths'][0]['routeType']['active']


print a['10.0.0.0/16']['bgpRoutePaths'][1]['asPathEntry']['asPath'], ' ', a['10.0.0.0/16']['bgpRoutePaths'][1]['med'], ' ', a['10.0.0.0/16']['bgpRoutePaths'][1]['routeType']['active']
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this myself!

```
  for k,v in a.iteritems():
  add = k
  for i in range (0,len(a.values()[0]['bgpRoutePaths'])):
   aspath = a.values()[0]['bgpRoutePaths'][i]['asPathEntry'].get('asPath')
   active = a.values()[0]['bgpRoutePaths'][i]['routeType'].get('active')
   print add,aspath,med,active

Output:
10.0.0.0/16 65404,65315 i 0 True
10.0.0.0/16 65407  65315 65317 65000 i 0 False
```